# Partition by Rows equivalent in pandas (python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using Azure Machine Learning Studio and what to add a running total on my dataset. This includes a date column, and I want to sum all the rows (for a group) on or before the row date.

In SQL Server, I would use:

```
    SELECT [t1].*,
SUM([t1].[Amount (Settlement CCY)) 
OVER (
  PARTITION BY [t1].[Contract Ref], [t1].[LOBCode], [t1].[Superline], [t1].[Occupation], [t1].[TransType], [t1].[SettCCY]
  ORDER BY     [t1].[Transaction Date] ASC
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
       AND     CURRENT ROW
)
FROM [t1]
GROUP BY [t1].[contract ref], [t1].[Transaction date], [t1].[LOBCode], [t1].[Superline], [t1].[Occupation], [t1].[TransType], [t1].[SettCCY]
```

but Azure Machine learning uses SQLite where the Over / Partition clauses aren't implemented.

I've tried an alternative in python/pandas:

```
dataframe1 = dataframe1.assign(cumAMTscTD=dataframe1.groupby(['ContractRef', 'Basis', 'LOBCode', 'Superline', 'Occupation', 'TransType', 'SettCCY'])['AmtSettCCY'].transform('sum')).sort_values(['ContractRef','TransDate'])
```

but this sums up everything for the group, not just the those for the dates up toe current row. I assume therefore it doesn't cover the:

```
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
   AND     CURRENT ROW
```

How would I acheive this?

Comment: Your code as written is not syntactically correct.  The additional columns in the `partition by` are not available, because they are not part of the aggregation.  I assume they are not actually necessary -- that is, the contract ref is sufficient.

Comment: thanks - that's actually because they are necessary, and i added them later (in the python) and just chucked them into the sql when i posted here and forgot the groupby. i also don't have a chance to run this in sql server to double check syntax, since i don't have access to the data in sql server, only once in the Azure ML Studio. I've amended the code (though it still may not be right, due to above)

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, you can implement the logic as:

```
with t as (
      select t1.contract_ref, t1.transaction_date, sum(t1.amount) as amount
      from t1
      group by t1.contract_ref, t1.transaction_date
     )
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.amount)
        from t t2
        where t2.contract_ref = t.contract_ref and
              t2.transaction_date <= t.transaction_date
       ) as running_amount
from t;
```

Comment: thank you. however, the performance of this query isn't acceptable - it's currently been running on AzureML for over 8 minutes and not completed yet (dataset is circa 260k rows)

Comment: @Dave . . . You don't have many opportunities to optimize such a query in SQLite.  Well, you have one.  Instead of a CTE, save `t` to a table and create indexes on `contracct_ref` and `transaction_date`.